Using Powershell 7 test files for unix or windows format
I have a vendor who sends 5-10 files a month.  Recently they started sending us a mixture of Unix format files among the Windows format files. This vendor is notoriously difficult to work with so this problem will be quicker solved by myself.
I have a short Powershell 7 script that works for the Unix files but creates havoc with the Windows files:
$Files = Get-ChildItem '\\XD1\Vendor_Incoming\*.csv'

foreach($file in $Files){
    (Get-Content -Raw -Path $file) -replace "`n","`r`n" |  Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $file
}

After searching SO and general google searches, I have yet to find an efficient method to test each file for its file format within the foreach statement, something like:
foreach($f in $Files){ If(thisfileisUnix){Process-File} }

Thank you for your time.

You could replace \r\n FIRST with \n then replace \n with \r\n. As it stands a Windows file with \r\n will have the \n replaced so you end up with \r\r\n, but if you do my procedure it would end up with what you want just \r\n.

Why does it matter?  Get-content will open both unix text and windows text and give the same result.


Your immediate problem, just to spell it out, is that you're blindly replacing "`n" (LF) instances with "`r`n" (CRLF) sequences, which means that files that already have CRLF sequences are accidentally corrupted, because you're effectively turning their CRLF sequences into CRCRLF sequences ("`r`r`n").

Note:

Both solutions below rely on reading each file into memory in full.
If that is undesired, a more complex solution is needed, as demonstrated in Santiago's answer.

A pragmatic solution that avoids this problem is to simply test for the presence of at least one "`r`n" (CRLF sequence) in the file's content and, if not found, assume that the file uses Unix-format newlines, "`n" (LF) only, and that the content therefore needs transforming:
Get-ChildItem '\\XD1\Vendor_Incoming\*.csv' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $text = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
    $isUnixFormat = -not $text.Contains("`r`n")
    if ($isUnixFormat) {
      $text.Replace("`n", "`r`n") |
        Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName
    }
  }

Note that Set-Content uses its default character encoding, as it knows nothing about the original file's encoding, so you may have to pass an -Encoding argument.

Here's a more robust, regex-based solution, which, however, is only necessary if there's a chance that any given file may contain a mix of LF and CRLF newlines:
Get-ChildItem '\\XD1\Vendor_Incoming\*.csv' | 
 ForEach-Object {
   $original = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
   $modified = $original -replace '(?<!\r)\n', "`r`n"
   if (-not [object]::ReferenceEquals($original, $modified)) {
      Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Value $modified
   }
 }


The above uses a regex with a negative lookbehind assertion ((?<!...)) to match only \n ("`n", LF) characters not preceded by \r ("`r", CR) and replace them with "`r`n" (Windows-format CRLF newlines).

It then tests whether any actual replacements were made, taking advantage of the fact that -replace, the regular-expression-based string replacement operator, returns the input string as-is if no actual replacement was made.

Only if an actual replacement was made is the modified content written back to the input file.



This is something you can use to avoid reading the files as a whole unless needed however, as you may note, the solution is quite cumbersome.
Basically, stream reading the files wouldn't be an option in this case as you wouldn't be able to determine the new line characters used, since stream reading splits them on new line.
The next approach you can take is reading the file bytes to see if you can find a CR char (`r) to determine if the was saved in a Windows environment or not, this would avoid reading the file content as whole and making unnecessary replacements.
class FileFormat {
    static hidden [char] $CR = "`r"
    static hidden [char] $LF = "`n"

    static [bool] IsUnix([string] $path) {
        $stream = $null
        try {
            $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($path)
            while (($byte = $stream.ReadByte()) -ne -1) {
                # if the file has a CR char we can tell that is windows
                if ($byte -eq [FileFormat]::CR) {
                    # exit early here
                    return $false
                }
                # if the previous condition didn't end this loop early
                # and we found a LF char we can tell that the delimiter is LF only
                if ($byte -eq [FileFormat]::LF) {
                    return $true
                }
            }
            # here is for the file is a single line and no line feed
            # you can return `$false` here to avoid opening the file again
            return $false
        }
        finally {
            if ($stream) {
                $stream.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem '\\XD1\Vendor_Incoming\*.csv') {
    if (-not [FileFormat]::IsUnix($file.FullName)) {
        # nothing to do here, go to next file
        continue
    }

    (Get-Content -Raw -Path $file) -replace "`n", "`r`n" |
        Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $file
}

